# MKMapView does not read the given coordinates

Tags: ios, mkmapview, mapkit

ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "MapKit/MapKit.h"
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <MKMapViewDelegate>
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet MKMapView *mapView;
@end
```

ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"
@interface ViewController ()
@end

@implementation ViewController


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

//Setting Region
//MKCoordinateRegion *myRegion;

//Center
CLLocationCoordinate2D center;
center.longitude = 55.316667;
center.latitude = 25.266667;

//SPAN
MKCoordinateSpan span;
span.latitudeDelta = 0.30f;
span.longitudeDelta = 0.30f;

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

As you see my code seems to be fine, and normally it should show the location given in latitude and longtitude values. But instead it shows this :

[image]

I am working in Xcode 5 with iOS 6.

Any ideas about the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Nowhere in the code shown does it "give the coordinates to the map view" so why should it do anything?

All the code does is:

1. Declares local variables called `center` and `span` in the `viewDidLoad` method.
2. Sets the values of these local variables (which the map view knows nothing about).
3. The `viewDidLoad` method ends (doing *nothing* with the values of the local variables).

Adding this line after setting `center` and `span` actually *gives* the coordinates to the map view so that it shows those coordinates:

```
mapView.region = MKCoordinateRegionMake(center, span);
```

(Assuming, of course, that the `mapView` IBOutlet is connected to the MKMapView in the xib.)

Now, this will center the map view at the coordinates you specified and that's it.

If you were expecting any other effects (such as a pin appearing at the coordinates), you'll need to create an annotation with those coordinates and tell the map view to add it.

Comment: I thought these are the coordintes :  

center.longitude = 55.316667;
center.latitude = 25.266667;

Comment: As I said, `center` is just a local variable you've declared and set.  The map view doesn't know anything about it until you actually give it to the map view by doing something like setting the map view's `region`.